# pipe tcpdump grep into perl

Tags: linux, perl, grep, pipe

In order to thwart a persistent hacker I have developed a tcpdump command which prints failed authentications plus the preceding 4 lines to the console.  Since sometimes I have to sleep, I would like to write a program to automatically add the IP to the firewall when the failed login is printed.

simplified example:

```
tcpdump [options] | grep [username] | perl -en [
    isolate username using regex;
    if username is the target username,
        examine previous lines looping until IP is detected;
    append properly formatted firewall command to firewall file;
    run firewall file]
```

I've got the tcpdump and the grep working.  I know enough about Perl to program this in a script file but the command line Perl has me stumped.

Comment: Show us an example of the incoming string you're trying to match against, what you're trying to extract, and any current solutions you've attempted, and we will be able to better help you.

Comment: If you know how to write the script, why not just pipe your tcpdump to the script? Multi-line Perl on the command line is pretty ugly.

Comment: "command-line Perl" is no different than a Perl script. You just have to quote your Perl code to protect it from the shell. But there is really no reason this has to be after `perl -e`; just write a script.

Comment: good idea ... I'll send it to a script

Comment: ok I created the script but I can't get the input into it.  tail -f messages | grep --line-buffered "auth failure:" | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$10}' | test3.pl  ... test3.pl never sees the input ... I tried ARGV and STDIN methods ... but if I leave off the last pipe and test3.pl I see what test3.pl should be seeing:  Feb 3 16:09:36 [user=someusername]

Comment: @xivix: Your `awk` may be buffering. You don't need that awk, perl has a perfectly good [`split`](http://p3rl.org/split). It should come in on STDIN.

Answer (score 2):

For what you're trying to do, I would suggest another route, and install a service such as [denyhosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/), which can detect repeated failed login attempts, log them, and automatically block them.

denyhosts is available from http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net - or is likely available on the repositories for your flavour of Linux.

Comment: well I've looked at denyhosts and fail2ban and it seems they use logs.  I never see the IPs in the logs so I have had to use tcpdump to extract the IP from the raw data.  Am I missing something with denyhosts?

Comment: If I remember rightly, denyhosts checks for failed SSH login attempts, then adds the source IP/hostname to the /etc/hosts.deny file after it reaches a certain threshold, which prevents that source from connecting again, and lets you review it.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this after?